# Setting IP Restrictions to all slots in an AppService Web App using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have a PS script which contains something like this to set IP restrictions on a Web App. This works great, however our PROD Web App has a Staging slot. How can I set the same restrictions in all slots? Unfortunately this is not yet supported by the portal..

```
# Update IP restrictions if modified
$WebAppConfig.properties.ipSecurityRestrictions = $ArrayList
$WebAppConfig | Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config  -ResourceName $WebApp/web -ApiVersion $APIVersion -Force | Out-Null
```

Huge thanks!

Comment: Just use the same command to do that, modify the `ResourceName` with your slot name.

Comment: Humm.. if I have a WebApp called "ChatService" with a slot called "Staging" then what name should I pass to *ResourceName* ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the script as below, my Webapp named `joywebapp2`, the slot named `slot1`, the script set the slot with the same `IpSecurityRestrictions` of the Webapp, if you have several slots, just use a loop.

```
$IpSecurityRestrictions = (Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Name joywebapp2).SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions
$slot = Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Name joywebapp2 -Slot slot1
$slot.SiteConfig.ipSecurityRestrictions = $IpSecurityRestrictions
$slot | Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot
```

**Update**:

If you want to use [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.3.0) module, the command should be  like as below.

```
$IpSecurityRestrictions = (Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Name joywebapp2).SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions
$slot = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Name joywebapp2 -Slot slot1
$slot.SiteConfig.ipSecurityRestrictions = $IpSecurityRestrictions
$slot | Set-AzWebAppSlot
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting this error: "The property 'ipSecurityRestrictions' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."   Any particular API version this need to run with?

Comment: I simply do not see that property when I do a "$slot.SiteConfig | Select-Object" ...

Comment: @JoseParra It should work fine, https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPgSr.png , what is the version of your `AzureRM` powershell module? Could you test it with my complete script? Besides, the `AzureRM` module has been basically deprecated, I recommend you to migrate it to `Az` module, see my update.

Comment: Perfect! I was not aware of the Az modules. Many thanks for your answer